# What's the green toy set besides Yondu's bed in "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2"...?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, object-identification, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

What's the green toy set besides Yondu's bed, during his farewell ceremony in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*...? From what I can tell, it was placed there by Gamora.

[image]

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=6&v=fizkUmk3Jtk) shows the whole scene.

Comment: Some of the items are from Earth and others aren't. I doubt this alien object has a name.

Comment: Yes it clearly is a toy of an alien animal. To me it looks like an elephant with 2 trunks. with multiple large nostrils on the trunks. I would think it might be a toy of an animal (or fictional animal) from Gamora's home world.